# spring boot boostrap bean override

Tags: java, spring, spring-cloud

In my `spring.factories` I have such a definition:

```
org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.BootstrapConfiguration=\
     MyBootstrapConfiguration
```

In `MyBootstrapConfiguration` I have :

```
@Configuration
public class MyBootstrapConfiguration {
    
     @Bean
     @ConditionalOnMissingBean
     public ApiClient apiClient() {
         return someClient;
     }
}
```

Now in my test (`junit-5` and `@SpringBootTest`), I would like to override this bean. Notice the `@ConditionalOnMissingBean`... If I can hook somehow to a "before" my bootstrap is started, to provide that `ApiClient`, that method `apiClient` would obviously not be called and I would be happy.

Please notice that `MyBootstrapConfiguration` is not something I have control of - its an invariant to me. For non-bootstrap configuration this is easily doable, but is there a way to do this for bootstrap?

Comment: Can you make a TestBootstrapConfiguration that extends MyBootstrapConfiguration and uses your "test" bean instead (and update the spring.factories to point at your TestConfiguration instead of the original)?

Comment: You should add an `@ConditionalOnProperty` on the given `@Configuration`. That way you can easily disable it. All other alternatives are quite complex via properties in the `@SpringBootTest` annotation.

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas no, unfortunately. If I could do that - I could just do `@ConditionalOnProperty` and that would solve it

Comment: @roookeee oh! the datus guy is here also (`wind57`...), I can't do that. it's an external dependency :( I don't care about complexity, a hint may be?

Comment: Having a `@ConditionalOnMissingBean` in a bootstrap `@Configuration` seems like a bigger-ish design issue - so you have zero control? No userland bean could ever override it. Maybe `@BootstrapWith` can help you here. I doubt it but maybe `@TestConfiguration` would take precedence inside the `@SpringBootTest`

Comment: adding a test bootstrap configuration with an order of highest precedence in your test spring.factories should work.

Comment: @spencergibb darn, that was easy. can you make this an answer please?

Comment: @Eugene I've added an answer

Comment: @spencergibb right, thank you. I have already accepted it and upvoted. Thank you for the help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given a test configuration class:

```
@Configuration
public class TestBootstrapConfiguration implements Ordered {
    
    @Bean
    public ApiClient testApiClient() {
        return testApiClient;
    }

    @Override
    public int getOrder() {
        return Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE;
    }
}
```

In `src/test/resources/META-INF/spring.factories`

```
org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.BootstrapConfiguration=\
TestBootstrapConfiguration
```